R - Filter to only include grouped rows that contain all values in a vector
Goal: Find all dates where the only color present is blue or yellow
If there are 2 colors then they BOTH need to be blue and yellow
If there's one color then it can be either one
In the example dataset:

2024-01-01 is ruled out because it has purple - and because it has 3
unique colors, so it's impossible that it can only be yellow and blue

2024-03-27 is OK since it only has blue

2024-05-15 is OK since it has blue AND yellow

2024-06-08 is ruled out because it has orange (this is the situation I don't know how to do hence the ??????)
library(tidyverse)

 dates <- c(rep("2024-01-01",3), "2024-03-27", rep("2024-05-15",2), rep("2024-06-08",2))
 color <- c("blue","purple","yellow","blue","blue", "yellow", "yellow","orange")

 df <- tibble(dates, color)
 df


 df %>% 
   group_by(dates) %>% 
   mutate(unique_colors_per_day = n_distinct(color)) %>% 
   ungroup() %>% 
   filter(unique_colors_per_day == 1 & color %in% c("blue", "yellow") |
            unique_colors_per_day == 2 & color "??????")




Is it okay if yellow or blue is repeated within a date -- would you want to keep that instance?

Yes, that would be preferred

library(dplyr)

df |>
  filter(n_distinct(color) <= 2, (n_distinct(color) == 1 & color %in% c('blue', 'yellow') | 
                                    all(c('blue', 'yellow') %in% color)), .by = dates)

